# How can I programmatically extract the app name and version number?

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I want to populate a WAMS table in the UnhandledException event, and I've got this code:

```
private async void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
        Debugger.Break();
    }
    PLATYPIRUS_WAMS_EXCEPTIONLOG pruwamsel = new PLATYPIRUS_WAMS_EXCEPTIONLOG();
    pruwamsel.appNameAndVersion = "Platypi R Us for WP8 v. 3.14";
    pruwamsel.ExceptionMsg = args.ExceptionObject.Message;
    pruwamsel.InnerException = args.ExceptionObject.InnerException.ToString();
    pruwamsel.ExceptionToStr = args.ToString();
    pruwamsel.dateTimeOffsetStamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    await App.MobileService.GetTable<PLATYPIRUS_WAMS_EXCEPTIONLOG>().InsertAsync(pruwamsel); 
}
```

...but I don't really want to hardcode the app name and version. How can I extract those programmatically?

### UPDATE

Incorporating the two ideas, I end up with:

```
private async void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
        Debugger.Break();
    }

    string appName;
    string appVersion;
    var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
    {
        XmlResolver = new XmlXapResolver()
    };

    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("WMAppManifest.xml", xmlReaderSettings))
    {
        xmlReader.ReadToDescendant("App");

        appName = xmlReader.GetAttribute("Title");
        appVersion = xmlReader.GetAttribute("Version");
    }

    PLATYPIRUS_WAMS_EXCEPTIONLOG pruwamsel = new PLATYPIRUS_WAMS_EXCEPTIONLOG();
    pruwamsel.appNameAndVersion = string.Format("{0} {1}", appName, appVersion);
    pruwamsel.ExceptionMsg = args.ExceptionObject.Message;
    pruwamsel.InnerException = args.ExceptionObject.InnerException.ToString();
    pruwamsel.ExceptionToStr = args.ExceptionObject.ToString();
    pruwamsel.dateTimeOffsetStamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow; 
    await App.MobileService.GetTable<PLATYPIRUS_WAMS_EXCEPTIONLOG>().InsertAsync(pruwamsel); 
}
```

Comment: Why not save `args.ExceptionObject.ToString()`? You'll lose part of the stack trace if you don't save it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application name and version are registered in WMAppManifest.xml file.

By using this [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Generating-a-Windows-Phone-9d19f939) and replacing the parts refering to "ProductID" with "Title" and "Version", I managed to get to this code:

```
var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    XmlResolver = new XmlXapResolver()
};

using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("WMAppManifest.xml", xmlReaderSettings))
{
    xmlReader.ReadToDescendant("App");

    var AppName = xmlReader.GetAttribute("Title");
    var AppVersion = xmlReader.GetAttribute("Version");
}
```